# Card incomplete or snipped in bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Hello StackOverflow community

I have an accordion with a card but this last is not showing successfully in the button in bottom.

In the next image is shown as the card is snipped.
[image: Snipped card]

Attach an example

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Snipped card</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container mt-3 mb-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anayarojo/pen/XoLOzg?editors=1000

Can you help me to show the card completely?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove **class="accordion"** from **id="accordionExample"**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container mt-3 mb-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="accordionExample">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: another way you can solve this with css if you dont want to remove class.

`.accordion .card{border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf !important;}` 

this becouse "bootstrap/scss/card.scss:296" "border-bottom:0" setting.

Comment: Now I understand that if I don´t have more than one card I don't need an accordion